# Adding MS Teams Tab (Planner) result in BadRequest

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

When trying to create a planner tab via graph api it always ends in a BadRequest error.
I tried following request:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<tenant>/channels/<id>/tabs`

Body:

```
{
    "displayName": "Planner",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.planner",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId:": "<planId>",
        "contentUrl": "https://tasks.office.com/<tenant>/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId=<planId>",
        "removeUrl": "https://tasks.office.com/<tenant>/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId=<planId>",
        "websiteUrl": "https://tasks.office.com/<tenant>/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId=<planId>"
    }
}
```

Result:

```
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity"
```

I also tried using the `teamsAppId` property instead of `teamsApp@odata.bind`. It ends up in another error: `The navigation bind for the teamsApp was missing in request.`

The request seems to be right when checking the graph api documentation.

Comment: We can see this issue, we are looking into this Thanks.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT is there an update from your side?

Comment: We filed a bug for this, We will update you once it is fixed.

Comment: The issue is no longer repro at our end.